# NodeJS / ReactJS: Manipular Token

Tags: node.js, react, jwt

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

Eu tenho uma API com NodeJS que realiza a autenticação do usuário (método POST), gerando um Token (jwt) e devolvendo o mesmo:

```
module.exports = {
async authenticate(req, res) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const response = await Person.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

    if (!response)
        return res.send({ error: 'User not found.'});

    if(!await bcrypt.compare(password, response.password))
        return res.send({ error: 'Invalid password.'});

    response.password = undefined;

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: response.id }, authConfig.secret, {
        expiresIn: 86400,
    });

    res.send({
        token,
    });
},
}
```

No meu frontend (ReactJS), após o usuário clicar no botão Login, eu tenho o seguinte evento:

```
handleSubimit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!this.canBeSubmitted()) { return; }

    if (this.state.email === '')
    {
        this.setState({
            erros: { email: "The 'Email' field is required." }
        });
        console.log(this.state.erros.email);
        return;
    };

    if (this.state.password === '')
    {
        this.setState({
            erros: { password: "The 'Password' field is required." }
        });
        console.log(this.state.erros.password);
        return;
    };

    const response = await api.post('/authenticate', {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
    });

    if (response.data.error)
    {
        //do something here later
        return;
    }

    const token = response.data.token;

    api.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = token;

    this.props.history.push('/main')
};
```

Nessa parte do código, eu estou enviado os dados do usuário pra API fazer as validações e retornar o Token, em seguida, eu salvo o Token no "headers" e redireciono para a página "Main".

Acontece que nesta página, eu faço algumas requisições na API, e para essas requisições, existe um "Middlewares" e ele não está conseguindo pegar o valor do Token que foi salvo no "headers".

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

if(!authHeader)
    return res.status(401).send({ error: 'No token provided.' });

const parts = authHeader.split(' ');

if (!parts.length === 2)
    return res.status(401).send({ error: 'Token error.' });

const [ scheme, token ] = parts;

if (!/^Bearer$/i.test(scheme))
    return res.status(401).send({ error: 'Token malformatted.' });

jwt.verify(token, authConfig.secret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return res.status(401).send({ error: 'Token invalid.' });

    req.userId = decoded.id;
    return next();
})
}
```

Alguém consegue ajudar?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, é só um palpite olhando por cima mas veja,

```
api.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = token;
```

vc define isso no front e logo depois vai para outra rota, essa configuração só é valida no objeto api que você usou naquela pagina quando você mudou de pagina e importou o objeto api novamente ele já é um novo sem essa configuração.
Assim o seu Middlewares não pega o token pois nas proximas requisições realmente não existe um token, sugiro que guarde ele no armazenamento do navegador e passe ele quando estiver fazendo as requisições.